# Disabled un input con onchange

Tags: javascript, laravel

Tengo un formulario en el que si no a seleccionado un almacén no puede escribir una referencia por lo cual lo tengo deshabilitado pero la función no hace la acción.

```
<label for="warehouse">* Almacén</label>
<select id="warehouse_id" onChange="myDisFunction()">
 ... </select>

<label for="inventory_id">* Referencia</label>
<input type="text" id="inventory_id">

<script>
    function myDisFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("warehouse_id").value;
    if(warehouse_id != null){
        inventory_id.disabled =false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ya lo edite, asi es como lo tengo ahora si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo más simple podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
var x = document.getElementById('inventory_id');
x.disabled = true;

function myDisFunction(element) {
  y = element.value;
  
  if(y == "0"){
    x.disabled = true;
  }else{
    x.disabled = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="warehouse">* Almacén</label>
<select onChange="myDisFunction(this)">
  <option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<label>* Referencia</label>
<input id="inventory_id" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas:

1. De entrada, el `input` debería aparecer como `disabled`
2. Tienes que referenciar al `input` por su id, para habilitarlo o no, cosa que no haces.
3. Tienes que verificar el valor `selectedIndex` del `select` para saber si han sido seleccionados o no. En el código de ejemplo he puesto un `option` por defecto para evitar confusiones. Esto permite dos cosas: desmarcar una opción que se haya elegido por error, volviendo a ese `option` por defecto; y volver a deshabilitar el `input` en ese caso. Ambas cosas serán harto difíciles cuando no imposibles sin ese `option` por defecto.

```js
function myDisFunction() {
  var selWarehouse = document.getElementById("warehouse_id");
  var refInput = document.getElementById("ref_id");
  refInput.disabled = (!selWarehouse.selectedIndex > 0);

}
```

```html
<label for="warehouse">* Almacén</label>
<select id="warehouse_id" onChange="myDisFunction()">
  <option selected>-- Seleccione --</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<label for="inventory_id">* Referencia</label>
<input type="text" id="ref_id" disabled>
```

Finalmente, te recomiendo que evites funciones in-line, son una mala práctica. Es mejor asignar eventos de escucha en el código Javascript, así, tu HTML es independiente. Poner funciones in-line significa poner en contexto HTML código Javascript, violando el principio de responsabilidad única.

Veamos un ejemplo usando escucha de eventos:

```js
const selWarehouse = document.querySelector('#warehouse_id');

selWarehouse.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  var refInput = document.getElementById("ref_id");
  refInput.disabled = (!selWarehouse.selectedIndex > 0);
});
```

```html
<label for="warehouse">* Almacén</label>
<select id="warehouse_id">
  <option selected>-- Seleccione --</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<label for="inventory_id">* Referencia</label>
<input type="text" id="ref_id" disabled>
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia? Hemos sacado la llamada in-line del HTML: `onChange="myDisFunction(this)"`, no la necesitamos, estamos escuchando los cambios del `select`, por su id.

¿Qué ventajas tiene esto? Ya dije una: respetamos el principio de responsabilidad única y facilitamos el mantenimiento del código. Imagina un proyecto grande, con miles de HTML en los que has puesto llamadas in-line. Ahora, esas funciones in-line necesitan otro parámetro o algo por el estilo. Te quiero ver, buscando entre los miles de HTML para cambiar esto: `onChange="myDisFunction(this)"` por esto: `onChange="myDisFunction(this,ooootroParametro)"`.